# jquery ui multiselect does not work with multiple + single select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, multi-select

i am using this plugin http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#single for multiselect, and wishfully for single select also, in the same page.
basically i have 2 selects - one is multiple the other is single, but i want to style them both the same.
so i try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        $("#altceva").multiselect({
            multiple: false,
            header: "Select an option",
            noneSelectedText: "Select an Option",
            selectedList: 1
        });

         $("#ceva").multiselect();
    });     
    </script>
```

and the select:

```
<select name="123_cat[]" id = "ceva" multiple="multiple" size="5">  
   <?php foreach($subcategories['categories'] as $sc) { ?>
   <optgroup label="<?php echo $sc['name']; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($sc['subcategories'] as $ss){?>                              
             <option id = "123_cat" value="<?php echo $ss['sid']; ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET['123_cat'])) { if(in_array($ss['sid'], $_GET['123_cat'])) echo "selected = 'selected'";} else { if(in_array($ss['sid'], $the_subcategories)) echo "selected = 'selected'"; } ?>><?php echo $ss['name']; ?></option>
        <?php }?>
```

```
    <label for="oras">Oras</label>  
       <select name="123_city" id = "altceva">      
          <?php foreach($ac as $rc) {?> 
             <option id = "123_city" value="<?php echo $rc['slug']; ?>" <?php if         (isset($_GET['123_city'])) { if ($rc['slug'] == $_GET['123_city']) echo 'selected =   "selected"';} else { if ($rc['slug'] == $my_data->city) echo 'selected = "selected"';} ?>>           <?php echo $rc['name']; ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>

            </select>
```

the problem is that multiselect works, but the single select doesn't work at all (i cannot select anything, the list gets dropped down, but nothing gets selected).
any idea why? thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Could you also please post the HTML of the `#ceva` select.

Comment: i have edited the question adding the select

Comment: solved it! in this plugin, single select is radio button not checkbox. i will post the answer immediatly just in case some other faces this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
altceva should be the id of multiselect dropdown and ceva should be the id of single dropdown.... Go for the below code...:)

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){ 
        $("#altceva").multiselect({
            multiple: true,
            header: false,
            noneSelectedText: "Select an Option",
            selectedList: 1
        });

         $("#ceva").multiselect({
            multiple: false,
            header: false,
            noneSelectedText: "Select an Option",
            selectedList: 1
        });
    });     
    </script>
```